# Problems with finatra and mustache lambdas

Tags: scala, lambda, mustache, finatra

I am experiencing some problems in using mustache lambdas within my finatra project. I would like to create my own translation function so I created something like this

```
import com.github.mustachejava.TemplateFunction

class TranslateFunction extends TemplateFuction {
  override def apply(input:String):String = {
   println("Translate " + input)
   return input
  }
}
```

but I cannot build it, sbt complains

```
[error] not found: type TemplateFuction
[error]   class TranslateFunction extends TemplateFuction {
[error]                                   ^
```

I am using finatra version 1.5.3 plus scala 2.10.3, does anyone has a project that works fine with finatra and mustache lambdas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your class declaration ("TemplateFunction" is misspelled, it's missing a 'n'). This works for me:

```
import com.github.mustachejava.TemplateFunction

class TranslateFunction extends TemplateFunction {
  override def apply(input:String):String = {
    println("Translate " + input)
    return input
  }
}
```

Comment: :| ouch, that is embarrassing